# subqueries in Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I M stuck in linq query where i m searching database & showing result using

```
DBSearchDataContext db = new DBSearchDataContext();
        object q = from b in db.Products
                   where b.ProductCode.Contains(val) |
                   b.ProductName.Contains(val) |
                   b.Specification.Contains(val) |
                   b.Description.Contains(val) |                       
                   b.Category.Contains(val) 
                   select b;

      GridView1.DataSource = q;
     GridView1.DataBind();
```

i can not display category name from category table where categoryID matches.

I do this in sql like this

how to do this in linq

```
SELECT ID, ProductCode, DisplayOrder, ProductName, imgThumb, inStock, Status, Amount, (SELECT Category FROM Category AS aaa WHERE (Products.CategoryID = CategoryID)) AS Category FROM Products ORDER BY ID DESC
```

help me

Comment: Why not use a regular LINQ **join** keyword? Do you know about joins in SQL? Your SQL query can be improved with a simple `INNER JOIN`. If your mapping is good, you won't even need a join and select `b.Category.Name` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing some mapping, why not use a simple join?

```
var q = from p in db.Products
        join c in db.Category on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
        where ...
        select new
        {
          p.ProductCode,
          ...,
          c.Category
        };
```

or with proper mappings:

```
var q = from p in db.Products
        where ...
        select new
        {
          p.ProductCode,
          ...,
          p.Category.Category
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the subquery into the Linq LET clause. See

- [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351707/linq-subquery)
- or [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1206492.aspx)

for example.